# Git alias ignoring global settings

Tags: git

I have the `relativePaths` setting for `git status` set in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[status]
  relativePaths = true
```

Then a `git` alias defined like this:

```
st = !git status
```

When I call `git status`, the `relativePaths` setting applies, but when I call the alias, it doesn't.

How can I get this to work?

*NOTE:*
*In my alias, I actually pipe the result of `git status` to `grep`, so I need to use the `!` shell syntax. I excluded that from this example because the behavior is the same without it*

Comment: It just occured to me that the `bash` invoked from the alias may not be reading my gitconfig, or may be missing env vars. Will check that out

Comment: Bash is not responsible for reading the gitconfig files.

Comment: You know what I meant

Answer (score 1):

The setting is probably applied, which you could check with an alias, e.g.:

```
[alias]
    check-status-rel = config --global --get status.relativePaths
```

The reason why it doesn't work for you is explained in `man git-config`, in the second paragraph of the `alias.*` settings' description:

```
   alias.*
       Command aliases for the git(1) command wrapper - e.g. after
       defining "alias.last = cat-file commit HEAD", the invocation "git
       last" is equivalent to "git cat-file commit HEAD". To avoid
       confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide
       existing Git commands are ignored. Arguments are split by spaces,
       the usual shell quoting and escaping is supported. A quote pair or
       a backslash can be used to quote them.

       If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it
       will be treated as a shell command. For example, defining
       "alias.new = !gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD", the invocation "git new"
       is equivalent to running the shell command "gitk --all --not
       ORIG_HEAD". Note that shell commands will be executed from the
       top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be
       the current directory.  GIT_PREFIX is set as returned by running
       git rev-parse --show-prefix from the original current directory.
       See git-rev-parse(1).
```

In short, Git aliases that are shell commands are always executed at the root directory of the repository.

Edit: Obviously, you can simply `cd` into the directory before running the commands:

```
[alias]
    st = "!cd \"$GIT_PREFIX\" && git status"
```